# Start some program with C# WinForms if it is not running now

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to start some program with C# WinForms if that program is not running right now. Right now my code opens, and it does not check that the program is running or not.

```
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Chrome.exe");
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Chrome";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var isRunning = Process.GetProcessesByName("Chrome").Length > 0;
Console.WriteLine(isRunning);
```

Output

```
True
```